# Unique Rank value for a subgroup within a group

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rank

I am trying to get a unique rank value (e.g. `{1, 2, 3, 4}` from a subgroup in my data.  SUMPRODUCT will produce `ties{1, 1, 3, 4}`, I am trying to add the COUNTIFS to the end to adjust the duplicate rank away.

```
                subgroup
col B   col M    rank
LMN       01      1
XYZ       02        
XYZ       02    
ABC       03    
ABC       01    
XYZ       01    
LMN       02      3
ABC       01    
LMN       03      4
LMN       03      4  'should be 5
ABC       02    
XYZ       02    
LMN       01      1  'should be 2
```

So far, I've come up with this.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$38705=B2)*(M2>$M$2:$M$38705))+countifs(B2:B38705=B2,M2:M38705=M2)
```

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: - Added a late additional answer to your OP to your interesting issue. Permit me to refer to your comment as of Jan 21 '16: 
"If you come up with any alternatives, **be sure to post**. 
I might even throw a bounty on this if *viable alternatives* are submitted."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The good news is that you can throw away the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) and replace it with a pair of [COUNTIFS functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED). The COUNTIFS can use full column references without detriment and is vastly more efficient than the SUMPRODUCT even with the SUMPRODUCT cell ranges limited to the extents of the data.

In N2 as a standard function,

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B, B2,M:M, "<"&M2)+COUNTIFS(B$2:B2, B2, M$2:M2, M2)
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: rank_unique_subgroups_sample_data]

**[Filtered Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PezLv.png)**

[image: rank_unique_subgroups_group_A filtered results]  [image: rank_unique_subgroups_group_B_ filtered results] [image: rank_unique_subgroups_group_C filtered results]

Comment: Cool.  I was playing with this but went a totally different way, that was not working, and gave up when the original question was deleted.

Comment: It as an interesting enough question and I had already started to screenshot the results so I thought it might be a worthwhile post. If you come up with any alternatives, be sure to post. I might even throw a bounty on this if viable alternatives are submitted.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution basing on OP**

Studying your post demanding to post any alternatives, I got interested in a solution based on your original approach via the `SUMPRODUCT` function.
IMO this could show the right way *for the sake of the art*:

**Applied method**

Get

- a) **all current ids** with  a group value lower or equal to the current value

  **MINUS**
- b) the number of current ids with the identical group value **starting count from the current row**

  **PLUS**
- c) the increment of 1

**Formula example, e.g. in cell N5:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$38705=$B5)*($M$2:$M$38705<=$M5))-COUNTIFS($B5:$B$38705,$B5,$M5:$M$38705,$M5)+1
```

**P.S.**

Of course, I agree with you preferring the above posted solution, too :+)