# Rank the top 5 entries in different criteria

Tags: excel

I have a table that I want to find the top X people in each of the different groups.

```
Unique Names       Number           Group
a                   30               1
b                   4                2
c                   19               3
d                   40               2
e                   1                1
f                   9                2
g                   15               3
```

I've ranked the top 5 people by number by using =index($A$2:$A$8,match(large($B$2:$B$8,1),$B$2:$B$8,0)). The 1 in the LARGE function I linked to a ranked range so that when I dragged down it changed up the number.

What I would like to do next is rank the top x number of people in each group. So top 3 in group 1.

I tried =index($A$2:$A$8,match("1"&large($B$2:$B$8,1),$C$2:$C$8&$B$2:$B$8,0)) but it didn't seem to work.

Thanks

EDIT: After looking at the answers below I have realised why they are not working for me. My actual data that I want to use the formula with have multiple entries of numbers. I have adjusted the example data to show this. The problem I have is that if there are duplicate numbers then it returns both of the names even if one is not in the group.

```
 Unique Names       Number           Group
    a                   30               1
    b                   30               2
    c                   19               3
    d                   40               2
    e                   1                1
    f                   30               2
    g                   15               3
```

Comment: I would look into the aggregate command function 14 I think it is

Comment: @ForwardEd How does using aggregate different from large? Doesn't =large(B3:B7,1) return the same as =aggregate(14,4,B3:B7,1)?

Comment: @AlexH are the differing row references in your formula intentional? shouldn't it be =INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(LARGE($B$2:$B$8,1),$B$2:$B$8,0))?

Comment: @UlliSchmid You are correct. Apologies

Comment: I edited the second set of example data to include duplicate number within the same group.  Just covers another possible issue, unless numbers are unique within the group.

Comment: Numbers are not unique to groups

Comment: See [Unique Rank value for a subgroup within a group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935673/unique-rank-value-for-a-subgroup-within-a-group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who offered help but for some reason none of your methods worked for me, which I am sure was to do with the quality of my data. I used an alternate method in the end which is slightly convoluted but seemed to work.

```
=IF($C2="1",RANK($B2,$B$2:$B$8,1)+ROW()/10000,-1)
```

Essentially using the rank function and adding a fraction to separate out duplicate values.

Answer (score 2):

Proof of Concept

[image: POC]

Use the following formula in the example above in cell F2 and copy down and to the right as needed.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,($C$2:$C$8=F$1)*($B$2:$B$8),ROW($A2)-1),$B$2:$B$8,0)),"")
```

In the header row provide the group numbers. or come up with a formula to augment and reset the group number as you copy down based on your X number in your question.

Explanation:

The AGGREGATE function unlike the large function is an array function without the need to use CSE.  As such we can add criteria to what we want to use.  In this case only 1 criteria was used and that was the group number.  in the formula it was the following part:

```
($C$2:$C$8=F$1)
```

If there were multiple criteria we would use either an + operator as an OR or we would use an * operator as an AND.

The 6 option in the aggregate function allows us to ignore errors.  This is useful when trying to get the small.  It is also useful for dealing with other information that may cause errors that do not need to be worried about.

As this is technically an array operation avoid using full column/row references as they can bog down your system.

The basics of what the over all formula is doing is building a list that match the group number you are interested in.  After filtering your numbers, it then determines which is the largest, second largest etc by what row you have copied down to.  It then determine what row the nth largest number occurs in through the match function, and finally it returns to the corresponding name to that row with the index function.

Comment: NOTE:  Not all AGGREGATE sub functions are array functions.  14 and 15 are for sure, I am not sure about the rest.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Do you know of a reason why it wouldn't work? As far as I can tell my actual data isn't that much different from the sample data I gave you, other than much larger. There are no blanks in it.

Comment: make sure the length of your ranges match.  ie A2:A1500 should be same for B2:B1500 or you could also do A1:A10 and B11:B20.  The number of rows in each range needs to be equal.

Comment: Also make sure AGGREGATE and IFERROR are supported by your version of Excel.

Comment: I've added an edit to the main explanation as I realised why the formula wasn't working. Do you have a solution? Really appreciate your help

Comment: Make sure the Group names in your column are spelt exactly the same in you header row.  Any trailing or leading spaces can throw things off.  "A" is not the same as " A", "A " or " A ".

Comment: They definitely are as they are indexed from the same location

Comment: uhm,  I am pretty sure there is a way to do this as well.  The breakdown is in the Index match segment.  I am thinking about this but its currently 10 am where I am and I have not slept yet.

Comment: No worries, appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

Building on all the other great answers.

Because you have the possibilities of duplicate values in each group we need to do this with two formulas.

First we need to get the numbers in order.  I used the Aggregate, but this could be done with the array LARGE(IF()) also:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$8/($C$2:$C$8=E$1),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

Then using that number and order we can reference, we can use a modified version of @ForwardEd's formula, using COUNTIF() to ensure we get the correct name in return.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$B$8)-ROW($B$2)+1)/(($C$2:$C$8=F$1)*($B$2:$B$8=E3)),COUNTIF(E$2:E2,E3)+1)),"")
```

This will count the number in the results returned and then bring in the correct name.

[image]

Comment: Thank you scott, I was working on a similar approach and banging my head against the wall.  I just got the D,B,F solution for group 2, originally was getting D,A,B.  Glad you posted your answer as I would have been beating my head against the wall longer trying to get it to fit all in one formula!

Comment: @ForwardEd sometimes the only way is to separate the steps.  This is one.  Of course there is always the vba route which we then could do it in one UDF.

Comment: I was going to mention that a VBA route may be the easier approach on this one back up in the initial comments,  but since VBA is not my forté and unable to easily produce quick code without syntax error, I thought it best to side step.  Though through other avenues I did leave it open for @MacroMan to jump in.

Answer (score 1):

You could also solve this with array formulas - to filter a group whose name is stored in E1, your code

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(LARGE($B$2:$B$8,1),$B$2:$B$8,0))
```

would then be adapted to

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(LARGE(IF($C$2:$C$8<>E1,-1,$B$2:$B$8),1),$B$2:$B$8,0))
```

Note: After entering an array formula, you have press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: Note: This is basically the same as @ForwardEd suggests, but less sophisticated.

Comment: similar but not quite the same.  Yours is more compact which I really like.  less chance for typos.  The advantage of the aggregate function in my opinion is you get array like calculations without the restriction of CSE { } for adjusting cell ranges and what not.