# Automatic, continuous sorting of values within groups

Tags: excel, max

Is it possible to list items from largest to smallest with criteria (like a "`SORTIF()`" function)?  I have a list of numerous different products.  I want to list the orders per day from largest to smallest for each product. I have included a small sample of what my list should look like:

```
1/8  Drill Bits         11   48
1/8  Drill Bits         12   24
1/8  Drill Bits         48   12
1/8  Drill Bits         24   12
1/8  Drill Bits         12   11
1/8 X 6 Drill Bits      12   12
1/8 X 6 Drill Bits       8   12
1/8 X 6 Drill Bits      12   12
1/8 X 6 Drill Bits       4   11
1/8 X 6 Drill Bits      12    8
9/64 X 6  Drill Bit     11    4
DB1/2 Deburring Tool     1    1
5/32  Drill Bits         1    1
3/16  Drill Bits        12   72
3/16  Drill Bits        72   60
3/16  Drill Bits        60   12
```

I would like to input a formula that lists orders for each product from largest to smallest as in the third column above.  Keep in mind that this is a large spreadsheet with thousands of lines so I need to be able to fill down.

Comment: So you want to sort on the right-most column, is that right? If that's so, highlight that column, click on Data and then Sort.

Comment: A helper column for the entry's Rank would make quick work of this. See [
Unique Rank value for a subgroup within a group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935673/unique-rank-value-for-a-subgroup-within-a-group).

Comment: Would help to edit your question to show the expected output

Comment: @Jeeped your suggestion works to rank my quantities per product but not sure how to use this helper column to list them from largest to smallest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, assuming your values begin in cells A2 and B2 and go down from there:

```
C2 (group index):          =IF(A2=A1, C1+1, 1)
D2 (group length):         =IF(A2=A3, D3, C2)
E2 (sorted version of B):  =LARGE(OFFSET(B2, 1-C2, 0, D2, 1), C2)
```

Then fill these down alongside your entries. If your entries are somewhere else on the sheet, shift all the formulas down and across accordingly.

Here's what happens:

- Cells in column C check whether they are the start of a new group; if so, they restart a row counter for that group; if not, they add 1 to the row counter from the previous row.
- Cells in column D check whether they are the end of a group; if so, they use the row counter for the current row (i.e., the group length); if not, they inherit the group length from the row below (further down in the group).
- Cells in column E use the OFFSET function to create a range that refers to the cells in the current group. Then they use the LARGE() function to choose the nth-largest entry from this range, where n is the position of the current row within the group.

I am assuming here that you are only interested in creating sorted groups based on the value in column A, and that you always want to begin a new group when that value changes. If you need to create new groups based on more than one column (e.g., date and product columns), you could use `AND(A2=A1, B2=B1)` instead of `A1=A1` in cell C2, and something similar in cell D2. I mention this even though no date is shown, because you said you "want to list the orders per day from largest to smallest for each product".

Comment: I am familiar with the sorting process.  Please note my last sentence:  "I would like to have orders for each product listed from largest to smallest in a _third_ column."  Keep in mind that this is a very large spreadsheet with products that sometimes have hundreds of quantities and I do not want to alter the first two columns since the order that they are in is important to my final outcome.  I want this to be a formula that fills down throughout my spreadsheet similar to `sumifs` or `maxifs.`

Comment: In my original answer I didn't realize you wanted the sorting to happen automatically and update dynamically; I thought you just wanted to sort based on the value in the third column. I have written a new answer above.

Comment: I fixed the typo and added some clarity to my example

Comment: This is works great!  ...I how would I tweak it to do exactly the same thing but from smallest to largest this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all your data (also with headers) and then go Home -> Find & filter (inside Editing section).

1. You can use option *Custom sorting*, when dialog shows and there you can choose what column you want to use and also if you want desc or asc.
2. Another option that might help you is *Filter* also in Home -> Find & filter (inside Editing section)
   This will add buttons to columns headers where you can set sorting and also filter.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I am familiar with the sorting process.  Please note my last sentence:  "I would like to have orders for each product listed from largest to smallest in a _third_ column."  Keep in mind that this is a very large spreadsheet with products that sometimes have hundreds of quantities and I do not want to alter the first two columns since the order that they are in is important to my final outcome.  I want this to be a formula that fills down throughout my spreadsheet similar to `sumifs` or `maxifs.`