# Rank subgroup within dynamic range

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, rank

I've got a ROI comparison table like this:

```
Month | ROI | 1  | 2  | 3  |
Jul   | A   | 1% | 
Jul   | B   | 3% |
Jul   | C   | 2% |
Jun   | A   | 4% | 6% |
Jun   | B   | 5% | 7% |
Jun   | C   | 6% | 8% |
May   | A   | 2% | 4% | 7% |
May   | C   | 3% | 5% | 6% |
```

I would like to rank each product's ROI (A, B and C) each month - so only rank the most right percentage for a given month.

But the range need to be dynamic as each product may have a different launch date. For example, the month of May doesn't have product B.

So the output will be:

```
   Month  | ROI | 1  | 2  | 3  | Rank
    Jul   | A   | 1% |    |    | 3
    Jul   | B   | 3% |    |    | 1
    Jul   | C   | 2% |    |    | 2
    Jun   | A   | 4% | 6% |    | 3
    Jun   | B   | 5% | 7% |    | 2
    Jun   | C   | 6% | 8% |    | 1
    May   | A   | 2% | 4% | 7% | 1
    May   | C   | 3% | 5% | 6% | 2
```

I'm thinking of using the Index/Match function:

```
=RANK(INDEX(G3:S3,MATCH(9^99,G3:S3,1)),G3:G5,0)
```

But I'm not sure how to make the G3:G5 dynamic.

Comment: See [Unique Rank value for a subgroup within a group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935673/unique-rank-value-for-a-subgroup-within-a-group). Use your *Jul, Jun, May, etc* as the grouping. The *1, 2, 3, etc* column could be retrieved with a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to get it working with the following formula in the rank column:

```
=RANK(OFFSET(G3,,SUM(--ISNUMBER(G3:S3))-1),
      OFFSET(G3,COUNTIF(E3:$E$999,E3)-COUNTIF($E$1:$E$999,E3),
                SUM(--ISNUMBER(G3:S3))-1,COUNTIF($E$1:$E$999,E3)))
```

(assuming your months are in `E1:E999`).

What this does is looks at `G3` and shifts to the rightmost non-empty (`ISNUMBER`) column using `OFFSET` and considers that value to be ranked in the `OFFSET` array where the month matches the current row's month.

Let's break apart the second `OFFSET` formula (assuming we are considering a `Jul` row):

- Start at `G3`.
- Row offset: count of `Jul` rows below current row (inclusive) - total count of `Jul` rows.
- Column offset: count of cells containing numbers in current row - 1
- Height: total count of `Jul` rows.

This is an array formula, so it must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note: The formula assumes that the rightmost values are the in same column if the month is the same. This holds in your given example, but I don't know whether it holds for your full data set. If this is not true in general, you can create a helper column using the first `OFFSET` piece of the formula

```
=OFFSET(G3,,SUM(--ISNUMBER(G3:S3))-1)
```

to get your rightmost number in each row and then do your ranking on that helper column.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a simple subgrouped ranking using the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED).

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, C:C, "<="&C2)
```

[image: rank_latest]

Modify the range of percentages to catch the right-most number from that row using [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) on a multiple column range with an approximate [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca).

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, INDEX(A:F, 0, MATCH(1E+99, A2:F2)), ">="&INDEX(A:F, ROW(2:2), MATCH(1E+99, A2:F2)))
```

[image: rank_latest_two]

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: Since you have already chosen an answer to your question, I will hope that this will illustrate conditional ranking with both ascending and descending order through the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED). It may be too late to mention it as I'm sure that you caught the inverse ranking orders between the two supplied formulas.