# Excel: Skipping values from a RANK

Tags: excel, rank

I'm running a league. There are 12 players. Every month each player gets a score.
The league ranking is based on the cumulative monthly score. That's easy enough.

Every month the top 3 players get a prize. Again, that's easy enough using Choose and Rank.

The complication is this: Occasionally a player cannot compete in a month.
In which case a substitute will take their place. The substitute's score counts towards the year end rankings, but does not count towards the monthly prize.

Can anyone think of a way that I can annotate the sheet so that the monthly rank can ignore the substitutes scores but the totals will still be correct?
At present I need two sheets.

Comment: It seems that your question is actually '*Is there a RANKIF function?*'. Not specifically, but [you can build one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935673/unique-rank-value-for-a-subgroup-within-a-group). Unfortunately you've provided no sample data (with expected results) or any other indication on what makes a substitute's score different from an original so no example formula can be offered.

Comment: "Unfortunately you've provided no sample data (with expected results) or any other indication on what makes a substitute's score different from an original" 
My question was, in part how I would indicate that a substitute's score is different. Visually I'm indicating it by a colored background and bold font, but I'm open to any other options that would get the job done.

Comment: Please [edit your above post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) and include some sample data which we can copy and paste into an Excel. This will make it easier for other to re-create your problem. Without it you are less likely to get an answer (more work for us). Also, a mock-up of the expected result (possibly a screenshot) would be nice.