# Race timing - Find position on person

Tags: excel

I have an excel that I am using to record the times of an Aquathlon. My sheet is as follows:

[Excel sheet showing rows and columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJYsM.png)

I have worked out how to calculate the competitors overall time and position. But now I need to also have their rank for the various categories. These being:

First Overall male
First Overall female
First U18 male
First U18 female

And so on...

Comment: See [Unique Rank value for a subgroup within a group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935673/unique-rank-value-for-a-subgroup-within-a-group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formula something similar to the below

```
=IF(E1="Male",SUMPRODUCT(($E$1:$E$9="Male")*($K$1:$K$9>K1))+1,"")
```

($K$1:$K$9>K1) part has to ($K$1:$K$9 < K1) if you want to rank in descending order.

The above formula is based on over all positions found in column K. Also, this formula filters based on the category found in column E. If you want any other category, you may need to customize this formula accordingly by changing the column references.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. This is almost perfect, however the above only works if they are male, is there a way to amend this based on whether they are either male or female?

Comment: I just specified Male in the formula. that is why it works only for male, if you change that to Female it will work only for female. For both, you can just try with =SUMPRODUCT(($E$1:$E$9=E1)*($K$1:$K$9>K1))+1

Comment: Yes the =SUMPRODUCT works perfectly so I can just have three cols, Overall Position, Gender Position and Age Group Position. Thanks a bunch. Just need to work out how to automatically populate the Overall Male and so on! Thanks a bunch