# Rank groups without duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've come across an issue where it would make my life much easier if I could rank values without having to separate them into groups. Is this possible with functions or vba? I've spent the last hour trying to find a solution and haven't had much luck. Sample file is attached.

EDIT: For those that want to close this for not being specific enough, how would you like me to better explain my problem? Would you like me to write an entire thesis on why I can't get ranked grouped results without duplicates?

| POSITION | STATUS | Expected Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |

Comment: Just under a minute of searching, try [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/rank-if-formula). It's a starting point for more research and possible answers.

Comment: I knew how to do that 10 years ago. The problem is obtaining results within groups without duplicates.

Comment: *"Would you like me to write an entire thesis on why I can't get ranked grouped results without duplicates?"*, no please no, but at least include your attempted formula in the post for debugging purposes. The answer is to use two `COUNTIFS()` functions in a row, one to test exactly as per the link I've shown, directly followed by a 2nd one to add records that are exactly the same up to that point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? **[Unique Rank value for a subgroup within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935673/unique-rank-value-for-a-subgroup-within-a-group)**

Comment: You should have searched on **SO** @Nick the solution was already there!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thank you! I did try searching SO but my terms must've been different than yours. And thanks to JvdV as well. After the 2nd response I was on the right track.

Comment: Ah okay, however @JvdV Sir, has already given a proper explanation and the link shall resolve the query, hope so.